# MediaPlayer create method return null object Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I followed many guides about the music player, but my problem is the create method because when i try to do start() the activity crash saying to me that musicplayer is null, here is the code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(CustomMediaPlayer.this, R.raw.aud_0101);
...
mediaPlayer.start();
```

the audio file is right inside the raw directory, so I don't know how could be the problem of this nullPointer, anyone have some idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The audio file might be of the [wrong format](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: no, all files are in .mp3 format

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri, android.view.SurfaceHolder, android.media.AudioAttributes, int) create returns null on failure. So probably the file is in wrong format. Try to see the logs, maybe you'll see some information that helps

Comment: Can you add the full trace of the crash?